# Integrating ROOT with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to use ROOT in my C++ project by I cannot get CMake to properly link the ROOT libraries. As of now, the project is only made up of a main.cpp file. Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(FirstProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

file(GLOB src "src/*.cpp")

# telling CMake where to find the ROOT installation
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{ROOTSYS})

# locating the ROOT package
find_package(ROOT REQUIRED COMPONENTS RIO Net Hist)

# include ROOT functions and macros
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${ROOT_CXX_FLAGS})

add_executable(main ${src})
# set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC -Wall)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC -Wextra)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC --std=c++17)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC -Iinclude)

target_link_libraries(main ${ROOT_LIBRARIES})
```

When I try to include the "TH1F.h" header in my main.cpp file, I get a ton of compile-time errors. Can anyone help me? Do I need to generate a dictionary?

Comment: "... I get a ton of compile-time errors. " is not an error description with which we can help you. Please, provide the **exact error messages**. At least the very first one.

Comment: I get so many I can't even reach the first one. The last ones sound like "this conflicts with previous declaration"

Comment: Redirect build process's output into the file, and then copy paste the first message from that file into the question post.

Comment: When you "*include ROOT functions and macros*", I think the command you want to use is `include(${ROOT_USE_FILE})`, not the `include_directories()` command. Your `include_directories()` command may be necessary, but you want to point to folder containing headers, so maybe just `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` instead of what is there now. Here's an [example](https://root.cern.ch/how/integrate-root-my-project-cmake).

Comment: How does `find_package()` populate the `ROOT_` variables? For example, if you add `message(ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to your CMake, what gets printed?

Comment: @squareskittles I get this:``` ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS:/home/Me/root/include```

Comment: Do you know what **version** of ROOT you are using? And how did you install ROOT? Did you follow a tutorial? Or did you clone from their Github [here](https://github.com/root-project/root) and build it from source?

Comment: @squareskittles I am using ROOT 6.16. I built it from source using Cmake as described on ROOT's website. The directory ``` ROOT_INCLUDE_DIRS:/home/Me/root/include``` is inside the ROOT build directory I created when I built it.

Comment: Ok, for version 6.16 and higher, there is some guidance [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/ROOT.html) which says that linking only imported targets (`ROOT::Core`, `ROOT::Hist`, etc) will provide the include directories also.

Comment: @squareskittles I had already read that guide. I even tried copying the simple project it describes as an example (the one where where he uses the target system without dictionaries) but I get the error ```/home/Me/simple_root_project/SimpleExample.cxx:1:10: fatal error: TLorentzVector.h: No such file or directory
 #include <TLorentzVector.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```

Comment: It sounds like something may not have built/installed successfully when you compiled and install the ROOT from source? Did you notice any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201093/discussion-between-fresh-and-squareskittles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my CmakeLists.txt file. It looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(FirstProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

file(GLOB src "src/*.cpp")

# locating the ROOT package
find_package(ROOT 6.16 CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(main ${src})
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC -Wall)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC -Wextra)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC --std=c++17)

target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ROOT::Hist)
```

The error I get now is

```
In file included from /home/Me/Desktop/MyDirectory/Code/FirstProject/src/header.cpp:1:0:
/home/Me/Desktop/MyDirectoory/Code/FirstProject/include/header.h:7:10: fatal error: TH1F.h: No such file or directory
 #include <TH1F.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```